# Why does this Regex match only show the first word in the capture variable, not the whole line?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm fairly new to Perl and Regexes, so please be patient with me if I misuse terminology.

I'm attempting to read a text file containing a movie script, and use a Regex to display all lines spoken by a particular character. Here's the excerpt I'm using:

```
BRIAN: Hello, mother.
MANDY: Don't you 'hello mother' me. What are all those people doing out ther    e?!
BRIAN: Oh. Well-- well, I, uh--
MANDY: Come on! What have you been up to, my lad?!
BRIAN: Well, uh, I think they must have popped by for something.
MANDY: 'Popped by'?! 'Swarmed by', more like! There's a multitude out there!
BRIAN: Mm, they-- they started following me yesterday.
MANDY: Well, they can stop following you right now. Now, stop following my son! You ought to be ashamed of yourselves.
FOLLOWERS: The Messiah! The Messiah! Show us the Messiah!
MANDY: The who?
FOLLOWERS: The Messiah!
MANDY: Huh, there's no Messiah in here. There's a mess, all right, but no Me    ssiah. Now, go away!
FOLLOWERS: The Messiah! The Messiah!
MANDY: Ooooh.
FOLLOWERS: Show us the Messiah! The Messiah! The Messiah! Show us the Messiah!
MANDY: Now, you listen here! He's not the Messiah. He's a very naughty boy! Now, go away!
```

And here's the code:

```
  1 use strict;
  2 use warnings;
  3 
  4 my $filename = "movie_script.txt";
  5 my $charname = $ARGV[0];
  6 
  7 if (-e $filename) {
  8     print "File exists.\n";
  9 } else {
 10     print "Alas, file does not exist.\n";
 11     exit 1;
 12 }
 13 
 14 open(my $fh, '<', $filename);
 15 
 16 my $match = "^($charname):.*/i";
 17 
 18 while (my $line = <$fh>) {
 19     if ( $line =~ m/^($charname):.*/i ) {
 20         $line =~ s/($charname): //i;
 21         print $line;                                                
 22     }
 23 }   
 24 print "\n";
 25 close $fh;
```

The code works fine, and when I run the program, passing "Brian" as a command-line argument, it only shows me Brian's lines, ditto if I enter "Mandy" or "Followers" (all case-insensitive.)

I'm trying to understand how capture variables work so I can more sensitively manipulate the text file. When I change line 21 to `print $1` instead of `print $line`, I would have expected the result to be the same, because the regex I've supplied should match any instance of "BRIAN", followed by a colon, then any number of characters until the end of the line.

When I do this, however, it just returns:

```
BRIANBRIANBRIANBRIAN
```

... Instead of the four lines belonging to Brian. So I tried swapping lines 22 and 21, putting the `print $1` statement before the regex substitution, but that returns the same result.

Why is the capture variable only showing the first word "BRIAN" and not the whole line? I'm sure it's a very simple error, but I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Lou for perl study books search in google `perl bookshelf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ( $line =~ m/^($charname):.*/i ) {
        $line =~ s/($charname): //i;
        print $line;                                                
    }
}
```

In your first line:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
```

You read a line from `$fh` into `$line`. That's fine. Then we look for your character name:

```
if ( $line =~ m/^($charname):.*/i ) {
```

You look for the character name at the start of the string (that's what `^` does), followed by a colon and then any other characters. That `.*` is pointless as it doesn't change what the regex matches at all.

But the parentheses that you put around `$charname` do something interesting. They capture the bit of the string that matches that part of the regex and store it in `$1`. Now, that's a bit wasteful, to be honest. As `$charname` is a fixed string, you already know what's going to end up in `$1`. It'll be "BRIAN" or whichever character you're looking for.

```
$line =~ s/($charname): //i;
print $line;
```

You then edit `$line` to remove the character name and the colon (and a space) from the start of the line. So you just get the line that is spoken. And you print that.

So far so good. Your code is a bit wasteful in places, but it does what you think.

Then you change the line:

```
print $line;
```

To:

```
print $1;
```

And you get confused :-)

But as we've already seen, the capturing parentheses will store "BRIAN" in `$1`. So if you print `$1`, you'll see "BRIAN".

You ask,

> Why is the capture variable only showing the first word "BRIAN" and not the whole line?

And the answer is, because that's what you've asked it to do. `$1` will contain what is inside the capturing parentheses. Which is `$charname`. Which is "BRIAN". The rest of the regex match is outside of the parentheses, so it doesn't end up in `$1`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I wish I could accept all three answers - you took time to patiently explain the capture variables, which I had obviously misunderstood, while mivk took time to explain the regexes. Thanks for your excellent and insightful explanation!

Answer (score 4):

`$1` is your first [capture group](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups): the part which matched the first pair of parentheses in your regex.

If you had a regex with 2 sets of parentheses, `$2` would be what matched the second part.

Here is an alternative to that part of your script:

```
my $match = qr/^($charname):\s*(.*)/i;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ( $line =~ m/$match/ ) {
        print "Character : $1\n",
              "text      : $2\n";                                                
    }
}
```

And just for fun, here would be a shortened version of your full script, with comments on the regex parts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "/tmp/y";
my $charname = $ARGV[0];

open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
  or die "Cannot find $filename\n";

my $match = qr/^\s* ($charname) \s*:\s* (.*)/ix;
#               |   |              |     |   | \ extended regex which allows spaces for readability
#               |   |              |     |   \ case insensitive
#               |   |              |     \ capture the rest of the line into $2
#               |   |              \ colon, optionally with spaces before and/or after
#               |   \ capture the name into $1
#               \ also accept spaces before the name


while ( <$fh> ) {   # use the default $_ variable instead of unneeded $line
    print "$2\n" if ( /$match/ );
}

print "\n";
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I wish I could accept this answer too. Your explanation of the regex is super helpful.

Comment: But what does `qr/` do that `m/` doesn't?

Comment: @Lou :  `qr/` is a "[Regexp Quote-Like Operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)" used to define a regex in a variable that can be used later inside `m/.../` (or `/.../`. The `m` is optional when using standard `/` regex syntax). I used that here because you had defined a `$match` variable in your original example.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. If I placed a regex into a scalar without the `qr/`, e.g. `$match = /^($charname):(.+)$/i` and then tried to run `print "x" if ( $match )`, I presume that wouldn't work?

Comment: @Lou Yes. The if condition wouldn't try to match anything, and would just always return true (since "$match" is neither 0 nor empty).

Answer (score 0):

Please investigate the following perl script how desired output can be achieved.

**NOTE:**

- Input test data stored in `__DATA__` block
- For reading from a file replace `<DATA>` with `<>` and run as `movie_script.pl BRIAN movie_script.txt`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $charname = shift or die 'Specify character';

say $charname;
/^$charname: (.*)\Z/ && say $1 for <DATA>;

__DATA__
BRIAN: Hello, mother.
MANDY: Don't you 'hello mother' me. What are all those people doing out ther    e?!
BRIAN: Oh. Well-- well, I, uh--
MANDY: Come on! What have you been up to, my lad?!
BRIAN: Well, uh, I think they must have popped by for something.
MANDY: 'Popped by'?! 'Swarmed by', more like! There's a multitude out there!
BRIAN: Mm, they-- they started following me yesterday.
MANDY: Well, they can stop following you right now. Now, stop following my son! You ought to be ashamed of yourselves.
FOLLOWERS: The Messiah! The Messiah! Show us the Messiah!
MANDY: The who?
FOLLOWERS: The Messiah!
MANDY: Huh, there's no Messiah in here. There's a mess, all right, but no Me    ssiah. Now, go away!
FOLLOWERS: The Messiah! The Messiah!
MANDY: Ooooh.
FOLLOWERS: Show us the Messiah! The Messiah! The Messiah! Show us the Messiah!
MANDY: Now, you listen here! He's not the Messiah. He's a very naughty boy! Now, go away!
```

Output sample `movie_script.pl BRIAN`

```
BRIAN
Hello, mother.
Oh. Well-- well, I, uh--
Well, uh, I think they must have popped by for something.
Mm, they-- they started following me yesterday.
```

Output sample `movie_script.pl FOLLOWERS`

```
FOLLOWERS
The Messiah! The Messiah! Show us the Messiah!
The Messiah!
The Messiah! The Messiah!
Show us the Messiah! The Messiah! The Messiah! Show us the Messiah!
```